# Display scroll bar in textbox when contents are beyond the bounds C#

Tags: c#, textbox, scrollbar

Is it possible to show/hide the scroll bar in a text box only when the line count in the text box is more than the number of lines displayed?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can set scroll bars to horizontal, vertical, or both but not to show/hide when necessary.

Comment: that's only in the bacic textbox - try RichTextBox

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Consider using the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) -- it has that behavior built in.

Comment: Ahh thank you Austin. Sometimes the most obvious solutions are the best :)

Comment: Don't forget to add the property ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" to the RichTextBox

Answer (score 9):

Thanks dummy, it works! Here short version of dummy answer in c#

Call this code at the end of your SizeChanged and TextChanged handlers:

```
Size textBoxRect = TextRenderer.MeasureText(
    this.YourTextBox.Text, 
    this.YourTextBox.Font, 
    new Size(this.YourTextBox.Width, int.MaxValue),
    TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
try
{
    this.YourTextBox.ScrollBars = textBoxRect.Height > this.YourTextBox.Height ? 
        ScrollBars.Vertical : 
        ScrollBars.None;
} catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
{
     // this sometimes throws a "failure to create window handle" error.
     // This might happen if the TextBox is unvisible and/or
     // too small to display a toolbar.
}
```

Comment: I think you have to substract  System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth and YourTextBox.Padding * 2 to YourTextBox.Width in "new Size(this.YourTextBox.Width, int.MaxValue)" sentence...

Answer (score 8):

```
Public Class TextBoxScrollbarPlugin
    Private WithEvents mTarget As TextBox

    ''' <summary>
    ''' After the Handle is created, mTarget.IsHandleCreated always returns
    ''' TRUE, even after HandleDestroyed is fired.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private mIsHandleCreated As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New(item As TextBox)
        mTarget = item
        mIsHandleCreated = mTarget.IsHandleCreated
    End Sub

    Private Sub Update()
        If Not mTarget.IsHandleCreated Then
            Return
        ElseIf Not mIsHandleCreated Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim textBoxRect = TextRenderer.MeasureText(mTarget.Text,
                                                   mTarget.Font,
                                                   New Size(mTarget.Width, Integer.MaxValue),
                                                   TextFormatFlags.WordBreak + TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl)

        Try
            If textBoxRect.Height > mTarget.Height Then
                mTarget.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
            Else
                mTarget.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
            End If
        Catch ex As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
            'this sometimes throws a "failure to create window handle"
            'error.
            'This might happen if the TextBox is unvisible and/or
            'to small to display a toolbar.
            If mLog.IsWarnEnabled Then mLog.Warn("Update()", ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub mTarget_HandleCreated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mTarget.HandleCreated
        mIsHandleCreated = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub mTarget_HandleDestroyed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mTarget.HandleDestroyed
        mIsHandleCreated = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub mTarget_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mTarget.SizeChanged
        Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mTarget_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mTarget.TextChanged
        Update()
    End Sub

End Class


Private mPlugins As New List(Of Object)
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    mPlugins.Add(New TextBoxScrollbarPlugin(txtBoxOne))
    mPlugins.Add(New TextBoxScrollbarPlugin(txtBoxTwo))
    mPlugins.Add(New TextBoxScrollbarPlugin(txtBoxThree))
End Sub
```

Comment: For those who must use Textbox (like I had to as it is a custom control) the above answer seems to work ok. I presumed I had to replace the + with OR to make it bitwise and I made the wordbreak conditional on the textbox.wordwrap value.  Hope that Helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've got tnimas solution working in vb.  Functions quite well as written and I've not seen the errors.

```
    Private Sub TextBoxSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Dim textBoxRect As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(TextBox.Text, TextBox.Font, New Size(TextBox.Width, Integer.MaxValue), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak Or TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl)
    Try
        TextBox.ScrollBar = If(textBoxRect.Height > TextBox.Height, ScrollBars.Vertical, ScrollBars.None)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle error
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself tried tnimas' solution but unable to catch the exception, so I use the WinApi to toggle the visible state of scrollbars instead like so:

```
Size textBoxRect = TextRenderer.MeasureText(YourTextBox.Text, YourTextBox.Font, new Size(YourTextBox.Width, int.MaxValue), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);

WinApi.ShowScrollBar(YourTextBox.Handle, (int)WinApi.ScrollBar.SB_VERT, textBoxRect.Height > YourTextBox.Height ? true : false);
```

This method does not cause the exception, though should note that hiding scrollbars like this will disable scroll messages, but this is fine if you're just hiding the scrollbars for when the text area can't be scrolled anyway.