# How to Hide the Vertical Scrollbar While the Textbox is not Full and Display When it is Full

Tags: c#, textbox, scrollbar

Can you please let me know how I can set the windows form textbox vertical scroller in a mood that Scrollbar displays only when the Text size is more that the space of textbox?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that automatic?

Comment: No, even when the box is empty but there is a fade out scroll line at there

Comment: You could check for yourself if the text is longer than viewable, and if it is, show the scrollbar. Otherwise, don't. Use the TextChanged event.

Comment: You can [use a RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407814/display-scroll-bar-in-textbox-when-contents-are-beyond-the-bounds-c-sharp) instead.

Comment: @JayRiggs's idea is better :P

Comment: Here is [another Solution][1] that might be interesting.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17719756/6297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think is to set the font of the text box to one of those having the same width for all characters, such as `Lucida Console`.

Then you measure how many characters you need to hit the end of the text box.

So, knowing that number, add to the `TextChanged` event a method to set scroll bar only if text has more than the maximum number.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int MaxChars = 10; //suppose that's the maximum
         if (textBox1.Text.Count() > MaxChars)
             textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
         else
             textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
    }
```

---

You can also calculate `MaxChars` with some kind of:

```
double param1 = figure out this number;
double param2 = figure out this number too;

int MaxChars = (int)(Math.Floor(param1*textBox1.Width - param2));
```

This way you can resize the component dinamically.

Answer (score 3):

Or if your textBox1 is multiline and contains e.g. 20 lines:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Split('\n').Length > 20)
        textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    else
        textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
internal static Size GetTextDimensions(Control control, Font font, string stringData)
{
    using (Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(stringData, font);
        return new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Height));
    }
}
```

Usuage:

```
        Size dimensions = ControlManager.GetTextDimensions(descriptionTextBox, descriptionTextBox.Font, descriptionTextBox.Text);

        descriptionTextBox.ScrollBars = dimensions.Height > 
                                        descriptionTextBox.Height ? 
                                        ScrollBars.Vertical : ScrollBars.None;
```

You may have to add or subtract depending on padding, but this works great.  Here is an extension method version:

```
    public static Size GetTextDimensions(this Control control, Font font, string stringData)
    {
        using (Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics())
        {
            SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(stringData, font);
            return new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Height));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Almoust perfect way, i was upgrade it: public static Size GetTextDimensions(this TextBox textBox)
{
    Font font = textBox.Font;
    string stringData = textBox.Text;
    int width = textBox.Width;
    using (Graphics g = textBox.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(stringData, font, width);
        return new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Height));
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox.Multiline)
        {
            textBox.ScrollBars = textBox.Text.Length > (textBox.Width + textBox.Height) / 1.30f ? ScrollBars.Vertical : textBox.Text.Split('\n').Length > textBox.Height / textBox.Font.Size/1.4f ? ScrollBars.Vertical : ScrollBars.None;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the `TextBox` inside a `ScrollViewer` and set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` for `ScrollViewer`. This code works (tested on Visual Studio 2012 & .NET 4.5):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Height="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        </TextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just wrapping in scrollviewer is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade method by Colby Africa

```
public static Size GetTextDimensions(this TextBox textBox)
{
    Font font = textBox.Font;
    string stringData = textBox.Text;
    int width = textBox.Width;
    using (Graphics g = textBox.CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(stringData, font, width);
        return new Size((int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(sizeF.Height));
    }
}
```